# Error: Another process has added the 'SOOrder' record. Please try again

Tags: acumatica

Is there a command that lets you know if another treatment is in progress ?
I have this error when I use the PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry.CopyOrder(PXAdapter adapter).

I add this code

```
 SOOrder cmd=CurrentSOOrder.Select();
  PXTrace.WriteInformation("CMD"+cmd.OrderNbr);
  cmd.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>().Usrtotalcout=totalcout;
  cmd.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>().Usrpourcentcout=0;
  if ((totalnet!=0) && (totalcout!=0))    
     {
           cmd.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>().Usrpourcentcout=(totalnet-totalcout)/(totalnet)*100;
     }    
          try
          {
          Base.Caches[typeof(PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder)].MarkUpdated(cmd);  
          Base.Document.View.RequestRefresh(); //\\
          }
           catch(Exception e)
            {
             PXTrace.WriteInformation(e.StackTrace);
            }
          return true;    
}
```

I execute this event with :

```
    protected void SOOrder_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
  {
      var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
      if (row==null) return;
      row.OverrideTaxZone=true;
      calcultotal(false); // calcul l'entête pour les webservices      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to another process, it is related to the timestamps on the record, take a look at this article here to help debug

https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/03/another-process-has-added-updated-deleted.html

The reasons you will see this error:

There was a key exception in the database when it was attempted to be inserted (e.g. primary key constraint error because Acumatica tried to insert two records with the same key)

Record was modified by another process (but this other process could be within your own code pressing the copy button) and has changed timestamp, therefore 0 records were modified when the UPDATE {table} statement was called.

Record was deleted by another process and when the DELETE Statement was called SQL returned 0 records modified.

I would step through your code while running a SQL Profiler and look for the moment that an UPDATE statement gets called where it returns "0 Records Modified" and that is the source of your problem. It usually has to do with the way you are structuring your code, you might need a cancel press to reload data in the cache before you begin etc etc, these issues are very specific and hard to have an easy solution over stackoverflow.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34315021)

Comment: Made some edits and undeleted